# RecyclerView is empty when display

Tags: java, android

I just a created Recycler View contains CardsView I already created an item and Model and adapter and I also set adapter this Recycelr View show as alert dialog I already populated this recycle view but it shows empty like this
[image]
and this is MainActivity.Java

```
package yourneeds.find.com.modifieritemsalertdialog;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button click;
    private List<ItemModifierModel> Modifiers;
    RecyclerView modifierItemList;
    Context context;
    public static ItemModifierAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


        initializeData();
        click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Button cancelBtn, okBtn;
                LayoutInflater inflater2 = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
                View view2 = inflater2.inflate(R.layout.remove_item_alert_dialog, null);
                 modifierItemList = (RecyclerView) view2.findViewById(R.id.ipcET);
                modifierItemList.setHasFixedSize(true);
                modifierItemList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
                LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
                modifierItemList.setLayoutManager(llm);
                okBtn = (Button) view2.findViewById(R.id.okBtn);
                cancelBtn = (Button) view2.findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn);
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

                modifierItemList.setAdapter(adapter);

                builder.setView(view2);
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                final AlertDialog alert11 = builder.create();





                okBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        alert11.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        alert11.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                alert11.show();
            }
        });
    }
    List<ItemModifierModel> ItemModifierModels;
    private void initializeData(){
        Modifiers = new ArrayList<>();
        Modifiers.add(new ItemModifierModel("204", "Regular"));
        Modifiers.add(new ItemModifierModel("205", "Regular"));
        Modifiers.add(new ItemModifierModel("206", "Regular"));
        Modifiers.add(new ItemModifierModel("207", "Regular"));
        Modifiers.add(new ItemModifierModel("208", "Regular"));
        Modifiers.add(new ItemModifierModel("209", "Regular"));
        Modifiers.add(new ItemModifierModel("210", "Regular"));
        Modifiers.add(new ItemModifierModel("211", "Regular"));
        Modifiers.add(new ItemModifierModel("212", "Regular"));
    }

    private void initializeAdapter(){
        ItemModifierAdapter adapter = new ItemModifierAdapter(Modifiers);

    }
}
```

Comment: many issues `initializeAdapter` never called , `adapter` initialization is local to this function etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your adapter inside the onClick() method, then add it on your recyclerview

```
modifierItemList.setLayoutManager(llm);
ItemModifierAdapter adapter = new ItemModifierAdapter(Modifiers);
modifierItemList.setAdapter(adapter);
okBtn = (Button) view2.findViewById(R.id.okBtn);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should make it work.

```
package yourneeds.find.com.modifieritemsalertdialog;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button click;
    private List<ItemModifierModel> Modifiers;
    RecyclerView modifierItemList;
    Context context;
    public static ItemModifierAdapter adapter;
    List<ItemModifierModel> ItemModifierModels;
    LinearLayoutManager llm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        modifierItemList = (RecyclerView) view2.findViewById(R.id.ipcET);
        modifierItemList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        llm = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
        modifierItemList.setLayoutManager(llm);

        Modifiers = new ArrayList<>();

        // Initialize Data
        Modifiers.add(new ItemModifierModel("204", "Regular"));
        Modifiers.add(new ItemModifierModel("205", "Regular"));
        Modifiers.add(new ItemModifierModel("206", "Regular"));
        Modifiers.add(new ItemModifierModel("207", "Regular"));
        Modifiers.add(new ItemModifierModel("208", "Regular"));
        Modifiers.add(new ItemModifierModel("209", "Regular"));
        Modifiers.add(new ItemModifierModel("210", "Regular"));
        Modifiers.add(new ItemModifierModel("211", "Regular"));
        Modifiers.add(new ItemModifierModel("212", "Regular"));

        // Initialize Adapter
        adapter = new ItemModifierAdapter(Modifiers);

        // Set Adapter
        modifierItemList.setAdapter(adapter);

        click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Button cancelBtn, okBtn;
                LayoutInflater inflater2 = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
                View view2 = inflater2.inflate(R.layout.remove_item_alert_dialog, null);
                okBtn = (Button) view2.findViewById(R.id.okBtn);
                cancelBtn = (Button) view2.findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn);              
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setView(view2);
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                final AlertDialog alert11 = builder.create();
                okBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        alert11.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        alert11.dismiss();
                    }
                });            
                alert11.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```